# Weird Clipping when Shading Smooth?

Tags: mesh, edit-mode, vertices, edges, smooth

I'm still quite new to Blender, but I was trying my hand at making a head for the first time. I normally sculpt it from a rounded cube, but I decided to try something different this time. All was normal until I chose to "Shade Smooth," then this unusual seam appeared around the jawline and back of the head. I managed to fix part of it by recreating the edges, but that did not work on the rest of it. What happened and what should I do?

[image: Unusual Seam on Head]

Comment: it can be inverted normals, or inner faces, or overlapping vertices

Comment: Any idea how I should go about fixing it? My mesh in the wireframe looks clear with no overlaps or anything and I've tried reconfiguring the vertices, but it continues to look like that when I feel them back in.

Comment: Rather than going by look, in edit mode, select all and use the M key to bring up the merge menu.  Select "merge by distance". If there are overlapping vertices this will find them.  Then deselect all, go to the select menu, Select All by Trait submenu and select Interior faces. If there are interior faces they'll be selected and you can delete them.

Comment: Please share your file

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions, Marty. However, merging by distance did not seem to do anything to my mesh (I even switched off the modifiers to make sure), and no faces were selected when searching for interior faces. Moonboots, how should I go about sharing my file?

Comment: Have you tried recalculating the normals?

Comment: I just did, and it worked! Thank you all for your suggestions!